# Angular.js - order list and save result

Tags: javascript, angularjs

This is a list of randomly ordered items:

```
<ul class="one" drag-drop="page.items">
   <li ng-repeat='item in page.items|orderBy:page.random as result'>
    <img ng-src="http://placecage.com/{{item.id*100}}/{{item.id*100}}">
    {{ item.name }}
  </li>
</ul>
<p> <b>Original</b></p>
<div>{{page.items || json}}</div>
<p><b>Ordered</b></p>
<div>{{result || json }}</div>
```

Under the list I get both the original list (which is sorted by ID) and the list after the random orderBy.

This is great, but the thing is that I use drag and drop on those list items and as I move them, the original list changes accordingly.

How can I save the first, original result and use it later on?

Answer (score 0):

Please provide jsfiddle if you can. Other than that arrays are passed by reference. so if you have var a and var b equal to same array when changing a you will change b as well. might wanna copy array. good way if you're using es6 is var c = [...yourArray];

try this and see if it works.

```
var a = [];
var b = a.concat(yourItemsArray);
```

then sort array b etc.